# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir los múltiplos de un número mediante una estructura repetitiva utilizando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, condiciones, bucles, while

¡Hola! Sigo en el intento de experimentar y aprender sobre estructuras repetitivas y quería agregar algunas condiciones a la estructura también.

En este caso, mi intención sería imprimir la cantidad de números que son múltiplos de 5 entre el 1 y 500 utilizando la estructura *while* por ejemplo. Me quedé con uno de mis últimos intentos, pero el código de abajo no me imprime dichos datos. ¿Qué estaría mal o qué le faltaría a dicho código?

```
let entero = 1;

while(entero <= 500){
    if(entero % 5 === 0){
        $("#pResultado").append(`${entero}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: De hecho ese `while` estaría bloqueando tu salida, pues veo que le falta dentro el incremento `entero++` si no nunca sumará 1 y siempre se quedaría en el valor inicial lo cual lo haría ciclarse de forma infinita.

Comment: Es cierto, me di cuenta tarde.

Answer (score 1):

Resolución:

```
let entero = 1;

while(entero <= 450){
    entero++;
    if(entero % 5 === 0){
        $("#pResultado").append(`${entero} <br>`);
    }
}
```